# jquery ajax gets fired on load instead of on blur

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function called applyToDetailRows, which I call on load, as well as when the input section of my page gets re-drawn via ajax.  this function, attaches a bunch of events to the input fields that get drawn.  One of the events on a field is blur, which triggers an ajax call to fetch student info.  The problem is that the blur ajax trigger fires every time the **page loads** for each field, rather than firing **on blur**.  And this only happens if the function is defined inside of applyToDetailRows.  If I pull it out of applyToDetailRows, it works fine.

one thing to note is that I also have auto-complete defined in applyToDetailRows in the similar manner, and it works fine. But not this.

```
    function applyToDetailRows() {
        $(":input[data-getstudent]").each(function() {
            $(this).on('blur', function () {
                var elem = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(elem).attr('data-getstudent'),
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        studentNumber: $(elem).val()
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }

/* some other definitions */

//applyToDetailRows called

applyToDetailRows();
```

Comment: You should use event delegation instead of re-applying the function after each request

Comment: how would I accomplish that for each one of my fields that gets re-drawn/added in the future?

Comment: No, as of jQuery 1.7 you need to use `.on()`. Something along these lines: `$(document.body).on("blur", ":input[data-getstudent]", function(){ ... });`

Comment: yep, just figured it out, it works!

Comment: Thanks a lot man. if you respond, i'll surely mark it as an answer :)

Comment: i used the following:  $(document).on('blur',':input[data-getstudent]', function () {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would prefer to use event delegation instead of re-applying the function after each request since it is possible you may be binding it wrong or more than once.

```
$(document).on("blur", ":input[data-getstudent]", function(){
  /* AJAX */
});
```

You can replace `document` with a common parent of all the `input` elements that is closer in the DOM tree to them than it.

Comment: another question:  how would I accomplish this for auto-complete? currently, i have something like $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
                    var elem = this;
                    $(this).autocomplete({

Comment: @Riz, you can't unless the plugin `.autocomplete()` let's you do it. So, you will actually need to still bind it manually for each new element