# jQuery onblur event fires on load instead of on blur when using ajax in wordpress front end

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using ajax in WordPress front end as suggested by wordpress codex in this article http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

I setup everything exaclty in this article, this is the code i use

```
$(document).ready(function(){



            jQuery("#jw_email").on("blur", function(){

            var jw_email = $(this).val();

                jQuery.post(
                    // see tip #1 for how we declare global javascript variables
                    MyAjax.ajaxurl,
                    {
                        // here we declare the parameters to send along with the request
                        // this means the following action hooks will be fired:
                        // wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit and wp_ajax_myajax-submit
                        action : 'rcv-checkuser',

                        // other parameters can be added along with "action"
                        jw_email : jw_email,
                        postCommentNonce : MyAjax.postCommentNonce
                    },
                    function( response ) {
                         $("#userid").val(response);
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                );

            });





});
```

Now the problem i am having is

```
jQuery("#jw_email").on("blur", function(){
```

the blur event in the above line fires once everytime the page loads & the function rcv-checkuser executed before even the blur event occurs

However right from the second time, the blur even works as expected.

But the first time when the page loads, onblur fires "on load" instead "on blur".

How to prevent this

I tried this solution but isn't working
[jquery ajax gets fired on load instead of on blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652531/jquery-ajax-gets-fired-on-load-instead-of-on-blur)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are your requirements but I assume this ajax call shouldn't happen even when the field is empty so just try put an condition

**if(jQuery("#jw_email").val() != ''){**

```
jQuery(this).on("blur", function(){

var jw_email = $(this).val();

    jQuery.post(
        // see tip #1 for how we declare global javascript variables
        MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            // here we declare the parameters to send along with the request
            // this means the following action hooks will be fired:
            // wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit and wp_ajax_myajax-submit
            action : 'rcv-checkuser',

            // other parameters can be added along with "action"
            jw_email : jw_email,
            postCommentNonce : MyAjax.postCommentNonce
        },
        function( response ) {
             $("#userid").val(response);
            console.log(response);
        }
    );

});
```

**}**

I presume the field will be empty on load and hence would stop the ajax call

Hope it helps!

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I can do that, But i am curious to know why the onblur fires when page load, i also tried focusout, The same happening. I guess wordpress experts only knows the answer, because this happens only when using it with wordpress, the same code works great on a sperate JS file